# How to arrange system of linear equations side by side

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.8 in,bottom=0.8 in,left=0.5 in,right=0.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{aligned}[t]
(1)~2x-y+z &= 9&\\
3x-y+z&= 6&\\
4x-y+2z&= 7&\\
-x+y-z&= 4&
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}[t]
(2)~x+y+z &= 6&\\
x-y+2z&= 5&\\
3x+y+z&= 8&\\
2x-2y+3z&= 7&
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}[t]
(3)~3x+3y+2z &= 1&\\
x+2y+0z&= 4&\\
0x+10y+3z&= -2&\\
2x-3y-z&= 5&
\end{aligned}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please be more elaborate with your question?  Also, if you insert LaTeX-code, mark it and press ^K (CTRL-K), to format it as a code block.  Your code ist rather more than complete.  There are at least one or two sections of code after `\end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the package{autoaligne} (http://mirrors.acm.jhu.edu/ctan/macros/generic/autoaligne/autoaligne-fr.pdf  doc in french), it handles the vertical alignment of the terms very well and can be used both in the text (this is the case here), in a math environment \ [] or $ $ or other.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}
%% Need to insert a math environment here!
\autoaligne{
(1)~ 2x-y+z = 9\\
  3x-y+z= 6\\
  4x-y+2z= 7\\
  \-x+y-z= 4
}
\hfill
\autoaligne{
  (2)~x+y+z = 6\\
  x-y+2z= 5\\
  3x+y+z= 8\\
  2x-2y+3z= 7
}
\hfill
\autoaligne{
  (3)~3x+3y+2z = 1\\
  x+2y+0z= 4\\
  0x+10y+3z= \-2\\
  2x-3y-z= 5
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to put the `aligned` into math mode by, lets say `\[...\]`?

Here is a corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%% Need to insert a math environment here!
\[
\begin{aligned}[t]
  (1)~2x-y+z &= 9&\\
  3x-y+z&= 6&\\
  4x-y+2z&= 7&\\
  -x+y-z&= 4&
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  (2)~x+y+z &= 6&\\
  x-y+2z&= 5&\\
  3x+y+z&= 8&\\
  2x-2y+3z&= 7&
\end{aligned}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  (3)~3x+3y+2z &= 1&\\
  x+2y+0z&= 4&\\
  0x+10y+3z&= -2&\\
  2x-3y-z&= 5&
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: OK thanks but how can i write all these from left side

Comment: I mean left justify